# Does Google-Chart-angularjs support "date" type?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I am using angular-google-chart https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart.

The code below works and the chart loads up.

```
x_axis = {id: "t", label: "Date", type: "string"};
y_axis = {id: "s", label: "Value (%)", type: "number"};            

ChartObj.data =
            {"cols": [
                horizontal_axis,
                vertical_axis
            ],
                "rows": [
                    {c:[{v: 1},{v: 98}]},{c:[{v: 2},{v: 90}]},{c:[{v: 3},{v: 120} ]}
                ]
            };
```

If I change the `x_axis` from string to date type;

```
x_axis = {id: "t", label: "Date", type: "date"};
```

the chart does not load and the error appears.

> google-visualization-errors-0", message: "c[Me] is not a function

When I checked the documentation https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes,
date type does seem supported. Did I miss out anything? Where can one find an accurate documentation for angular-google-chart? The examples so far seem to be in the form of code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to specify dates using [Google Chart Tools AngularJS Directive Module](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart):

```js
angular.module("chartApp", ["googlechart"])
.controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.chartObject.type = "BarChart";


        $scope.chartObject.data = {
            "cols": [
                { id: "s", label: "Date", type: "date" },
                { id: "t", label: "Precipitation (mm)", type: "number" },
            ],
            "rows": [
                {
                    c: [
                        { v: new Date(2000, 0, 1) },
                        { v: 40 },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    c: [
                        { v: new Date(2000, 1, 2) },
                        { v: 50 },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    c: [
                        { v: new Date(2000, 2, 1) },
                        { v: 35 },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    c: [
                        { v: new Date(2000, 3, 1) },
                        { v: 30 },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };

    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'AVERAGE MONTHLY PRECIPITATION OVER THE YEAR (RAINFALL, SNOW)',
        vAxis: {
           format: 'MMM', //display month part
        },
    };
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.0.11/ng-google-chart.js"></script>

<body ng-app='chartApp' ng-controller="GenericChartCtrl">
    <div google-chart chart="chartObject"  style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
</body>
```